# Is there any way to avoid interpolation between GPX locations in Xcode?

Tags: ios

I'm using a GPX file to move the user location across a number of locations.

The problem is that the distance between the locations can be pretty large. Xcode is interpolating between them and it takes ages.

Is there any way to get Xcode to jump discretely between the specified locations?